# What does booting and rebooting mean?

Tags: operating-system, boot

Could we use the word of **booting** to mean both **start** and **restart**? 
What is the difference between **booting** and **rebooting**?

Comment: This question rather belongs to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

booting comes from "pulling yourself up by your bootstraps". The computer starts itself based on a simple trigger.

re is a prefix meaning again. so rebooting is booting again after you booted, meaning booting a machine again after it was already running. Think shutdown into boot.